# How to slice string considering both ends are exclusive using regex?

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I have a string output like this-

`KActive[m[K: active (running) since Sat 2021-07-29 00:11:50 IST; 8h ago', {'command': 'service tmi status | grep Active'}`

I want to cut it from `active` to `ago`.
Final output should be-

`active (running) since Sat 2021-07-29 00:11:50 IST; 8h ago`

What is the best way to slice it in python? i am not looking for `string_name[start_index:stop_index]` rather I would like to know how to slice it using regex and python.

Comment: You can match the regular expression `\bactive .*? ago\b`. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/MdWcwt/1). The question mark causes the match to end with the first instance of `'ago'` (should there be more). The word boundaries (`\b`) prevent substrings of words such as 'reactive' and 'agony' from being matched.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the regex provided by Cary Swoveland you can do this easily with [`re.search()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search).

```py
import re

input_string = "KActive[m[K: active (running) since Sat 2021-07-29 00:11:50 IST; 8h ago', {'command': 'service tmi status | grep Active'}"

def get_status(string):
    match = re.search(r'\bstatus .*? ago\b', string)
    match = match.group(0)
    return match

print(get_status(input_string))
```